# Does a raw device need a file system?

Tags: filesystems, partition, hard-disk, devices

In order to bypass the operating system cache when reading a file, I used `O_DIRECT` flag when calling `open()`. In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_device) it says that there is no difference between the two. Yet, does defining a HD (or more specifically a partition) as a raw device allows to avoid using a file system? (In [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50397693/linux-device-without-a-file-system) a comment says it's impossible since a file system was already preformatted. )

Moreover, except from the file system question, If one can share a good guild for defining and working with raw device I would be really grateful.

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Well I execute some reading experiments to try and evaluate characteristic reading times. I was told that the file system itself might cause some overhead and I may try and use raw devices in order the eliminate this overhead. However, I wish to really understand that raw device might be of an aid, or it's redundant in case I use O_DIRECT flag. @EduardoTrápani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, accessing the raw device does not need a filesystem. Well, you could say you are using a virtual filesystem `/dev` but that's only needed to expose the name of the device, after that your i/o is going to the device.

But there are many levels of cache/buffering. Filesystem is just one of them, the system will have its own set and disk hardware does too. If you want to get even *closer* to the device you will need to access other interfaces.

You might be better off with an existing tool, say `dd` and `hdparm`. ["Test disk i/o performance with dd"](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-unix-test-disk-performance-with-dd-command/) or ["Disk Speed Test (Read/Write): HDD, SSD Performance in Linux"](https://www.shellhacks.com/disk-speed-test-read-write-hdd-ssd-perfomance-linux/).